# I want func locationManager(manager: CLLocationManager, didUpdateToLocation to be called even after app is killed?

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, core-location, cllocationmanager

After my app is killed I want to relaunch the app based on the location.speed paramater, I mean to say when the device speed is>5kmph I want my app to get open and one button needs to be clicked programatically?

Comment: There are limited scenarios in which you can use Core Location in the background. You should take a look at the [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/reference/corelocation/cllocationmanager#1669609)

Answer (score 0):

Set allowsBackgroundLocationUpdates = true

The default value is NO for allowsBackgroundLocationUpdates

If your app uses location in the background (without showing the blue status bar) you have to set allowsBackgroundLocationUpdates to YES in addition to setting the background mode capability in Info.plist. Otherwise location updates are only delivered in foreground. The advantage is that you can now have location managers with background location updates and other location managers with only foreground location updates in the same app. You can also reset the value to NO to change the behavior.

Comment: This will get executed while the app is in background. I need the delegate method of CLLocation manager didUpdateLocations to be called after the app is killed(after termination)

Comment: set allowsBackgroundLocationUpdates = YES .Check if this solves your problem.

Comment: The answer you gave is for the app when it is in background. But my problem is when the app is killed,I need didUpdateLocations method o be called frequently and run.

Comment: NOT POSSIBLE then :|

Answer (score 0):

NOT POSSIBLE.

You can not execute part of code when you process is killed. Its as simple as that.

You can do this in android with background sevice which run even when you app gets killed because background service is different process. But iOS don't allow to create background service.